# script & sheet timing out when trying to print large arrays in google script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop

## Background

I have a function that makes a REST API call using `UrlFetchApp` in Google Scripts.

But the response only returns 2000 records at a time. If there are more records, there is, in the response, a key called **nextRecordsUrl**, which contains the endpoint and parameters needed to get the next batch of records.

I use a **do...while** loop to iterate through, pushing the records into a predesignated array, make the next api call. And when it reaches the last batch of records, it exists the do-while loop, then prints (not sure if that's the right term here) the entire to a Google Sheet.

## The code

It looks like this:

```
function getCampaignAssociations() {
  clearPage('CampaignAssociations');
  var query = '?q=select+CampaignMember.FirstName,CampaignMember.LastName,CampaignMember.LeadId,CampaignMember.ContactId,CampaignMember.Name,CampaignMember.CampaignId,CampaignMember.SystemModstamp,CampaignMember.Email+from+CampaignMember+ORDER+BY+Email ASC,SystemModstamp+ASC';

  try {
    var arrCampAssociation = getInfoByQuery(query);

    if (arrCampAssociation.records.length < 1) {
      throw 'there are no records in this query';
    }

    var campaignAssoc = [];
    do {
      Logger.log(arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl);

      for (var i in arrCampAssociation.records) {
        let data = arrCampAssociation.records[i];
        let createDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data.SystemModstamp), "GMT", "dd-MM-YYYY");
        let a1 = "$A" + (parseInt(i) + 2);
        let nameFormula = '=IFERROR(INDEX(Campaigns,MATCH(' + a1 + ',Campaigns!$A$2:A,0),2),"")';
        let typeFormula = '=IFERROR(INDEX(Campaigns,MATCH(' + a1 + ',Campaigns!$A$2:A,0),3),"")';

        campaignAssoc.push([data.CampaignId, nameFormula, typeFormula, data.Email, data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.LeadId, data.ContactId, createDate]);
      }

      var arrCampAssociation = getQueryWithFullEndPoint(arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl);
      
    } while (arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl != null && arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl != undefined);

      let endRow = campAssocSheet.getLastRow(), 
       endColumn = campAssocSheet.getLastColumn(), 
       nameRange = campAssocSheet.getRange(2, 1, endRow, endColumn),
       destRange = campAssocSheet.getRange(2, 1, campaignAssoc.length, campaignAssoc[0].length);
      destRange.setValues(campaignAssoc);
      sheet.setNamedRange('CampaignAssociation', nameRange);


    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      Logger.log(arrCampAssociation);
      Logger.log(campaignAssoc);
      Logger.log(i);
    }
  }
```

## Issue

Everything works nicely until it comes to printing the array **campaignAssoc** to the Google Sheet.

See screenshot of the log below. It contains the endpoint for the next both. Notice the timestamp between the earlier logs and the timestamp between the last endPoint and the log where it timed out.

[image]

It seems to me that the issue is that when it comes to the printing of the data, it's having issues. If that's the case, have I overloaded the array? There are a total of over 36400 records.

## Second attempt

I've tried resetting the array at each loop and printing the array to Google sheet. This is just 2000 records at each attempt and I've definitely done more rows at 1 time, but that didn't help.

Here's the code for that attempt.

```
function getCampaignAssociations() {
  clearPage('CampaignAssociations');
  var query = '?q=select+CampaignMember.FirstName,CampaignMember.LastName,CampaignMember.LeadId,CampaignMember.ContactId,CampaignMember.Name,CampaignMember.CampaignId,CampaignMember.SystemModstamp,CampaignMember.Email+from+CampaignMember+ORDER+BY+Email ASC,SystemModstamp+ASC';

  try {
    var arrCampAssociation = getInfoByQuery(query);

    if (arrCampAssociation.records.length < 1) {
      throw 'there are no records in this query';
    }

    
    do {
      Logger.log(arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl);
      var campaignAssoc = [];
      for (var i in arrCampAssociation.records) {
        let data = arrCampAssociation.records[i];
        let createDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data.SystemModstamp), "GMT", "dd-MM-YYYY");
        let a1 = "$A" + (parseInt(i) + 2);
        let nameFormula = '=IFERROR(INDEX(Campaigns,MATCH(' + a1 + ',Campaigns!$A$2:A,0),2),"")';
        let typeFormula = '=IFERROR(INDEX(Campaigns,MATCH(' + a1 + ',Campaigns!$A$2:A,0),3),"")';

        campaignAssoc.push([data.CampaignId, nameFormula, typeFormula, data.Email, data.FirstName, data.LastName, data.LeadId, data.ContactId, createDate]);
        
      }
      let lastRow = campAssocSheet.getLastRow()+1;
      campAssocSheet.getRange(lastRow,1,campaignAssoc.length,campaignAssoc[0].length).setValues(campaignAssoc);
      var arrCampAssociation = getQueryWithFullEndPoint(arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl);
      
    } while (arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl != null && arrCampAssociation.nextRecordsUrl != undefined);

      let endRow = campAssocSheet.getLastRow(), 
       endColumn = campAssocSheet.getLastColumn(), 
       nameRange = campAssocSheet.getRange(2, 1, endRow, endColumn);

      sheet.setNamedRange('CampaignAssociation', nameRange);


    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      Logger.log(arrCampAssociation);
      Logger.log(campaignAssoc);
      Logger.log(i);
    }
  }
```

So here, each loop took a lot longer. Instead of being 1-2 seconds between each loop, it took 45 seconds to a minute between each and timed out after the 4th loop. See the log below:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Logger.log is limited to the number of lines it can display.  So the array output is truncated by Logger.log.  Check the lenght of `Logger.log("length = "+campaignAssoc.length);`

Comment: @TheWizEd, please explain what you are trying to solve or what you want me to find out.

Comment: You said you think the array is truncated.  I'm just saying Logger.log is not displaying the complete array.  Simply check the length of campaignAssoc to see if it is.

Comment: My point is more about the timeout. but for the record the answer is 36000. it only prints 4446

Comment: You may have to do it in batches